# Bind Java AtomicLong with javafx2 LongProperty

Tags: java, javafx-2

Can i use Java Atomic classes with javafx2 NumberProperty .

- As i want to use `AtomicLong` with `LongProperty`.
- **Update**
- I want to update javafx progressBar's progress value throw Atomic Class as the worker thread doesn't javafx environment .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to udpate progress bar, you can take a look on a Task class of javafx concurrent package.

In case of talk about non-javafx thread. Take a look on Platform.runLater() method, which allows to run runnable on JFX thread.

Comment: Thanks for yours kindly answer, yes i can update javafx thread progress and then bind thread progress with progressbar progress property.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when the values changes, you wan to update the screen.  AtomicLong doesn't have support for triggering such events so I suspect you should consider another approach.

Comment: there is no `value change Listener` in `Atomic Classes` .?